# Raw disk image from VDI file can be mounted using qemu-nbd but not loop device?

Tags: qemu, fdisk, disk-image, loop-device

I installed a very old Slack version (3.2) on VirtualBox and then converted it to RAW format (ext2). However, for some reason I'm unable to mount it using losetup but qemu-nbd works fine. Why?

I tried,
`losetup -P -f --show slack-3.2.img`

but it doesn't create partitions.
I modified /etc/default/grub so that GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="loop.max_part=63" and grub-mkconfig, etc. but it still won't create the partitions from the image.

I tried, `kpartx -av slack-3.2.img` and I get

```
read error, sector 0
read error, sector 1
read error, sector 29
```

I even tried `dd if=slack-3.2.img of=slack.part bs=512 skip=63 count=409185`

and `sudo losetup -P -f --show slack.part` but it still fails. Why won't it work?

`sudo fdisk -l slack-3.2.img`

```
Disk slack-3.2.img: 200 MiB, 209715200 bytes, 409600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device         Boot Start    End Sectors   Size Id Type
slack-3.2.img1         63 409247  409185 199.8M 83 Linux
```

Comment: About the grub change : did you reboot and check /proc/cmdline for the loop parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read error, sector 0

This indicates trouble of the kernel to access your file and I have the strong suspicion that vboxfs is causing it. I have a long open bug about it not supporting symlinks and hardlinks and I think they only fixed the former.

qemu-nbd OTOH will just read the file, so it is fine, but the kernel uses mmap and other low level accesses.

A solution would be to copy the image onto a ext2/4 on a (virtual) partition.

Comment: I copied the image file from the shared folder to a local directory and once I `losetup -P /dev/loop0 slack-3.2.img` I could see that the loop device was no longer read-only (which didn't happen before) and then I could see the new device `/dev/loop0p1`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because VirtualBox usually does not use raw files, but images with a special internal format.

To convert it to raw, use

```
qemu-img convert -O raw INPUT OUTPUT
```

An alternative explanation could be that you operate on a file, but many of the operations you try, expect a block device - and you get that from ndb or losetup.

```
losetup -o $((63 * 512)) /dev/loop7 FILE
```

Should give you the partition directly.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for your reply but your suggestions didn't work. I tried losetup with the offset before and even tried it with the sizelimit option as well but it still failed.

Comment: How does it fail? Losetup is just mapping a file onto a block device. Or do you store the file on an unusual filesystem?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't fail, it just doesn't create the new device (/dev/loop0p1) so that I can mount it. But yes, the file is on a filesystem, the vbox filesystem because I'm sharing the file inside a VM (but that shouldn't have an effect?). Basically I'm either on a Mac or a Windows PC desktop, so I'm either using a VirtualBox VM or a Docker container to run Linux commands to be able to mount the VDI file or RAW file. `qemu-nbd` works fine to mount the device, so I already have a working solution, it's just that I'd like to understand why losetup cannot successfully `--partscan` the image?

Comment: When I read `fdisk -l slack-3.2.img` and run `losetup --offset $((63*512)) --sizelimit $((409185*512)) /dev/loop0 slack-3.2.img` I should be able to mount /dev/loop0 but I get the error, `mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/loop0.` So I'm wondering if the ext2 file system has changed in some ways from version to version? Because I'm feeling that losetup won't perform `--partscan` successfully because it's assuming a block size of 1024 bytes? or some other assumption that doesn't apply to old disk formats?

Comment: @Dennis "But yes, the file is on a filesystem, the vbox filesystem ... (but that shouldn't have an effect?)" what makes you think that that shouldn't have any effect ;-) ? Please edit that info (with complete details) into your Q.

Comment: The vbox filesystem has serious limitations, e.g. could not hardlink files - and possibly also mmap which might be required for loop mounting.